# how to change gtk tab height in gtkrc file?

Tags: tabs, gtk

I want to change GTK tab (something like terminal tab or Firfox tab) height. I know that  `TKNotebook` can do this but I do not know which property is the height.
`GTKNotebook::height=xxx` does not work. By the way, can GTK change the height of the Firefox tab?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GTK can change Firefox appearance, as Firefox uses its own UI/widget system. There are probably extensions or themes that allow it to be changed.